# $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t}{n}}f(t)dt\in\mathbb{R}$, then $a_n\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue inegrable and assume that $f(t)\rightarrow 1$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Prove that for each positive integer $n$ we may define $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t}{n}}f(t)dt\in\mathbb{R}$ and prove that $a_n\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I guess you mean measurable instead of integrable?

Comment: @JohnMa This is the problem that I found so I'm not quite sure if it should be...

Comment: Is it possible that $f$ is integrable and $f(t)$ goes to $1$? Because there is a $T$ such that for $t>T$ then $f(t) \geq 1- \varepsilon$.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since this question does not meet with the generally accepted standards. Please add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and I can undelete my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t}{n}}dt = -e^{-\frac{t}{n}}|_0^{\infty} =  1.$$
Since $f(t) \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$, choose $T$ such that for $t > T$,
$$ |f(t) - 1| < \epsilon.$$
Then assuming $f$ is absolutely integrable, i.e., $\|f\|_{L_1} < \infty$,
\begin{align}
|a_n - 1| &\le \frac{1}{n}\left(\int_0^T e^{-\frac{t}{n}}|f(t)-1|dt + \int_T^\infty e^{-\frac{t}{n}}|f(t)-1|dt \right) \\
&\le \frac{1}{n}\left(T + \|f\|_{L_1}  + ne^{-\frac{T}{n}}\epsilon \right) \to \epsilon \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
\end{align}

To be more precise,
\begin{align}
\int_0^T e^{-\frac{t}{n}}|f(t)-1|dt &\le 
\int_0^T |f(t)|dt + \int_0^T 1dt \\
&\le \int_0^\infty |f(t)|dt + T =  \|f\|_{L_1} + T.
\end{align}

Comment: The supremum doesn't have to be finite, but I guess one can find an upper bound with $||f||_1 + 1$

Comment: @Falrach You are correct. Thanks for the comment. Assuming $f$ is absolutely integrable, I edited my answer. But not sure how to deal with that term only assuming $f$ is integrable...

Comment: @induction601 Isn't integrable by definition $\int |f| <\infty$? Anyway the function $f$ cannot be integable on $\mathbb R$, the OP needs to clarify that.

Comment: @JohnMa As I know, integrablity means $\int f < \infty$. And absolute integrablity means $\int |f| < \infty$.

Comment: I also understand integrability as $\int |f| < \infty$

Comment: @Falrach Oh I see. **Lebesgue** integrable by definition, $\int |f| < \infty$. Thanks.

Comment: @induction601 Can you please explain the last inequality? Thank you.

Comment: The last inequality is not right. The second integral is bounded by $\epsilon$, but does not go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. However, this turns out to be okay.

Comment: @robjohn You're right. The second integral is bounded by $\epsilon$.

Comment: @induction601 I am stuck in the calculation... Why is $\int_{0}^{T}e^{-\frac{T}{n}}|f(t)-1|dt\leq T+||f||_{L_1}$?

Comment: @2ndaccount See the details that I added.